# azure pipeline - set a variable based on the trigger path

Tags: azure, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-yaml

I am using Azure Pipelines and have the following situation:

I have one repository with the folders A and B (and many more in the future). If I run the pipeline manually, I do chose A or B and the pipeline does stuff with the files in that folder.
This is fine for my branches, but I also want an automatic trigger for my main branch.

How do I get a variable that depends on the path of the code change?

My trigger looks something like this:

```
trigger:
  branches:
    include:
      - main
  paths:
    include:
      - abc/xyz/A/*
      - abc/xyz/B/*
```

And all I need is a variable that is A or B now, depending on the path where the change occured.
(Ideally if there are changes in both folders the pipeline should trigger twice, but this is the next problem I have to take on)

Comment: This would be life-changer for some scenarios. Is sad that there is no way to achive that directly

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no direct way to achieve this.

As a work around, you could use git command to get the commit message from the code change in A and B, and set the commit message as variable.

```
git diff-tree --no-commit-id --name-only -r $(Build.SourceVersion)
```

If the changes is from Folder A. Set "FolderAUpdated" to ture

```
Write-Host "##vso[task.setvariable variable=FolderAUpdated]true"
```

And set conditions to check the variable value

"Custom conditions": `and(succeeded(), eq(variables['FolderAUpdated'], 'true'))`

> "(Ideally if there are changes in both folders the pipeline should
> trigger twice, but this is the next problem I have to take on)"

A good option for this would create two individual pipelines, if both folders have changes, two pipelines will be triggered.

Pipeline A

```
trigger:
  branches:
    include:
      - main
  paths:
    include:
      - abc/xyz/A/*
```

Pipeline B

```
trigger:
  branches:
    include:
      - main
  paths:
    include:
      - abc/xyz/B/*
```

Comment: I've went with something similar in the end, but I use only one pipeline with a parameter and two separate pipelines like in your example that trigger this other pipeline with that parameter set to A or B. 
This way I can also manually trigger the original pipeline and set the parameter myself in case I need to run the pipeline for a branch.

Answer (score -1):

```
trigger:
  branches:
    include:
      - main
      - dev
  paths:
    exclude:
      - azure-pipelines.yml
      - TfCodeandPlanValidation.yml
      - 'README.md'
  
variables:
  - name: tf_version
    value: latest
  - name: variablegroupname
    ${{ if eq(variables['Build.SourceBranchName'], 'main') }}:
      value: kv-Prod
    ${{ if eq(variables['Build.SourceBranchName'], 'dev') }}:
      value: kv-Dev
  - name: env
    ${{ if eq(variables['Build.SourceBranchName'], 'main') }}:
      value: prod
    ${{ if eq(variables['Build.SourceBranchName'], 'dev') }}:
      value: dev
```

Here I have mentioned it in the variable section.

Comment: this is depending on the branch, but I need it to depend on the path where the change occured (folder A or B). The trigger is only for one branch: main.

Comment: Sorry for that, I have misread it.